# Stop the app in background and again start running when it is launch

Tags: android

I am new to android.. 
I have a TimerApp in which i used a button when user pressed button timer starts.If unexpectedly user get calls/anything else timer should stop working after finishing call/other activity it should again start from where it is stopped.
Used TextField to display timer

got the below code from some tutorial

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

        }
    });

    pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

        }
    });

}
```

after the above code i placed onResume() but it is not working.When i click on menu option in emulator it should redirect to home screen again when the app is launched timer should start from the resumed state

Comment: show your code, please

Comment: @Salauyou I Edited my question.I dint wrote any code just practicing tutorial codes and modifying those

Answer (score 0):

You should use onPause, onResume methods. Please check this link;

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html